# How to remove multiple identical installed RPM packages?

Tags: linux, package-management, rpm

A host crashed near the end of some package update, and now I have an inconsistency I'd like to fix:

`rpm -Va` complains about dependency packages would be missing, but those packages are installed!

However when I use `rpm -qa package_name` I see the same package being installed multiple times (e.g. three times).

When I try to remove the package using `rpm -ve package_name`, `rpm` tells me:

> error: "package_name" specifies multiple packages:

But note that there is no output after the colon.
So when listing the packages using `rpm -qa package_name` I get a list of three identical packages (same release, same version, same architecture).
When I use the full package name for `rpm -ve`, I get the message about multiple packages again, but this time the full package names are listed.

How can I remove the duplicate packages in order to reinstall them cleanly?

`rpm` version is `4.14.3-150300.46.1.x86_64` of SLES 15 SP3

I had tried a `rpm -v --rebuilddb` already:
It did not output anything, nor did it change anything.

Comment: The "solution" in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/290906/320598 did not help.

Comment: @Mokubai I think the removed tags `inconsistency` (did not exist before) and `duplicate` were justified for this question.

Comment: They were both [meta tags](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1648/are-error-and-problem-meta-tags) that provide nearly no information about the subject of your question. "Inconsistency" could be applied to any number of topics and does nothing to actually focus on any specific problem, it requires other tags to define what it is "inconsistent" with. Same with "duplicate". https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/ Tags should provide information on their own, not just raise more questions.

Comment: From [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://superuser.com/help/tagging) "A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question." which `Inconsistency` does not do. Also "Do not use meta-tags in questions. Here are some tips to help you determine whether a tag is a meta-tag: **If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having configured automatic snapshots on BtrFS, I tried this:

1. `mkdir /var/lib/rpm/SAVED`
2. `mv /var/lib/rpm/* /var/lib/rpm/SAVED/`
3. Use `snapper list` to find the most recent useful snapshot number.
   In my case it was 439.
4. Copy the saved RPM database back to the system.
   After finding an empty `/var` in `/.snapshots/439/snapshot/var`, I realized that `/var/lib/rpm` is a symbolic link to `../../usr/lib/sysimage/rpm` (i.e.: `/usr/lib/sysimage/rpm` (a stupid concept IMHO, BTW).
   So I used `cp -a /.snapshots/439/snapshot/usr/lib/sysimage/rpm/* /var/lib/rpm/` to copy that part of the snapshot back into the system.
5. Next I inspected `/var/log/zypp/history` to find the packages that were removed after the snapshot (the system thinks those packages are still there), so I reinstalled them to make the RPM database consistent with the files.
6. Likewise I repeated the online updates (that may be in the filesystem, but not in the RPM database).
   Remember: That snapshot was taken *before* the failed updates, so the updates are not in the database.
7. Eventually I ran `rpm -Va` to find suspect output that might require a reinstall of the package.
   It looked good however!

So it seems the whole issue was a damaged or inconsistent RPM database, but the problem was not detected by RPM itself.